# How to solve Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I got an error when implementing ResNet 50 in Keras, I am setting the initialization values on input_tensor. I was currently working with this model ain this way and 6 days ago I got ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance. I tried with keras_placeholder and works but the last_layer starts to give me more troubles. I thought it was about the Keras version but I install other versions and they give me errors that I did not have. Anyone have any idea what I can do?

```
image_input = Input(shape=(width_shape, height_shape, 3))
m_Resnet50 = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-49ab3019852b> in <module>()
  1 image_input = Input(shape=(width_shape, height_shape, 3))
 ----> 2 m_Resnet50 = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
  3 
  4 m_Resnet50.summary()


 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
 1276                      keras_tensor.KerasTensor)):
 1277     raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' + str(type(x)) +
-> 1278                      '`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')
 1279   if ops.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
 1280     return isinstance(x, keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
```

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

Comment: You are mixing keras and tf.keras which are different libraries and cannot be used together.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to replicate your issue as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from keras import layers, Model, Input

width_shape = 224
height_shape = 224

image_input = Input(shape=(width_shape, height_shape, 3))
m_Resnet50 = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
m_Resnet50.summary()
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4d2f17c32b79> in <module>()
      9 
     10 image_input = Input(shape=(width_shape, height_shape, 3))
---> 11 m_Resnet50 = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
     12 m_Resnet50.summary()
     13 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in is_keras_tensor(x)
   1276                      keras_tensor.KerasTensor)):
   1277     raise ValueError('Unexpectedly found an instance of type `' + str(type(x)) +
-> 1278                      '`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.')
   1279   if ops.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
   1280     return isinstance(x, keras_tensor.KerasTensor)

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.
```

**Fixed code:**
Your issue can be resolved, if you can change imports as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, Input

width_shape = 224
height_shape = 224

image_input = Input(shape=(width_shape, height_shape, 3))
m_Resnet50 = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
#m_Resnet50.summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply import Input from keras.layers

Even I was getting the same error when I was trying as follows:

```
from keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3  
#(I was training on a different model, but that doesnt matter)
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
```

Instead of that try importing as:

```
from keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

inputCustom=Input(shape=(224,224,3))
net= EfficientNetB3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
input_tensor=inputCustom)

net.summary()
```

I hope this works, happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. Wherever you have imported keras, replace it by tensorflow.keras.
e.g:

```
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```