# Unable to save models in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to save models that I have trained

the code im using to save is:

`tf.keras.models.save_model(model, 'model_path/model', save_format='h5')`
or
`model.save('model_path/model')`
or
`model.save('model_path/model.h5')`

I get the same error using any of the above methods:

`TypeError: Unable to serialize KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(80, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.__operators__.getitem_10/strided_slice:0', description="created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_10'") to JSON. Unrecognized type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.`

Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It potentially seems like your imports such as Model, layers etc. are directly from keras instead of tensorflow.keras. Try to import them using tensorflow.keras so it may resolves the issue. Have a look at the given link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755194/how-to-solve-unexpectedly-found-an-instance-of-type-class-keras-engine-keras

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. @MuhammadHamzaSabir

Comment: Please share the minimal reproducible code of the model to understand the issue and help you to fix this error.